# convert plink dosage (.raw) format to ped format

Tags: linux, unix

raw) file which look like this

```
FID IID FA MO SEX PHENO SNP1 SNP2 SNP3

1 1 0 0 1 1 0 2 1

1 2 0 0 1 1 0 2 1

1 3 0 0 1 1 0 2 1
```

and map file

```
1 SNP1 20 A G

1 SNP2 45 T C

1 SNP3 56 A G
```

I want to recode my dosage file to ped format so it look like this:

```
FID IID FA MO SEX PHENO SNP1 SNP2 SNP3

1 1 0 0 1 1 AA CC AG

1 2 0 0 1 1 AA CC AG

1 3 0 0 1 1 AA CC AG
```

Thanks,

Manav

Comment: What's the conversion algorithm? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: The columns SNP1, SNP2 and SNP3 represent 0,1 or 2 copies of minor allele (5th column of map file). So if SNP1 is 0 that mean it does not have any minor allele, so no G. Therefore it would translate to AA. SNP2 is 2 which mean that it has two copies of minor allele, which will translate to CC.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$2,0]=$4$4 ; a[$2,1]=$4$5 ; a[$2,2]=$5$5 ; next} 
    $7~/^[0-2]$/ {$7=a["SNP1",$7] ; $8=a["SNP2",$8] ; $9=a["SNP3",$9]} 1' 
    map_file raw_file
```

Output:

```
FID IID FA MO SEX PHENO SNP1 SNP2 SNP3

1 1 0 0 1 1 AA CC AG

1 2 0 0 1 1 AA CC AG

1 3 0 0 1 1 AA CC AG
```